# Black box in screen after pressing Android menu button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am creating a library class in Android Studio for my internship. I have created a custom RelativeLayout that inflates the layout shown below.

I can't find this issue anywhere, so I hope someone is able to help me out.
I have a layout file that looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoFrame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I do need the FrameLayout, to be able to scale the VideoView where the VideoView's width is bigger then the parent this Layout is inflated into. I resize this VideoView dynamically on runtime-level, but that all works fine.

When I start the activity with this VideoView, everything is fine. 
Whenever I hit the **Android "Windows"-button** and return to the Activity, a black box appears.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIwX1.jpg)

It also happens in Portrait mode. Then the black box is even bigger than half the screen.

After changing screenOrientation, so rotating my tablet, for example, the black box is gone again.

I really have no clue, does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you playing video?

Comment: Yes, it contains a video that starts playing whenever this View is created. It's purpose is to be a background video that keeps looping.

Comment: Today I found that this black box only appears when the child of the FrameLayout has "android:layout_gravity="center"". Also, when I rotate screen to portrait and back, the black box is also gone. There is some kind of method triggered while rotating the screen that fixes the issue, but I still can't find it. Please help.